# Why Does nbclust in R not Converge Because of Graphic Settings?

Tags: r

How do the first 3 lines below permit my nbclust function [into res()] to run in R?

```
graphics.off()
par("mar")
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
res<-NbClust(Rand_4_1_12k, distance = "euclidean", min.nc=3, max.nc=7, 
         method = "complete", index = "all")
```

Just curious

Comment: we can't possibly answer this without a [mcve] ...

Comment: Just a very general question

Comment: Probably unanswerable in this form though. If `NbClust` uses a random component, e.g. for initialization, then successive runs could succeed or fail apparently arbitrarily. If you use `set.seed` to standardize the random number stream, you may see more consistent results (and have nothing to do with the graphics state?)

Comment: You can always type `NbClust` and work your way through the source code or contact the maintainer, `maintainer("NbClust")`.